# how could html file including public php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i am think about is it possible let a html file includes a public php file? cuz i used a html file as a front-end webpage, and using ajax to load outside php file to each div. let's say there are 2 divs and each of them loads different php file, here's the problem, there are some public functions that both 2 php file needs, but if i loaded the first php file which contains those public functions, when the second php file loaded it cannnot reach those public functions? is there any other methods except 'include' a head php file on each php files?

Comment: It sounds like you're confused about the differences between PHP and Javascript/jQuery. PHP is executed on the server, Javascript is executed on the client. When you make an AJAX request, the server is executing your PHP code and returning a value to the client, you're not "including" anything.

Comment: thank you @Kryten u made the point.

Comment: I can only agree with @Kryten too.